# Query Bugging in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Can anyone explain me about the hierarchical Queries in oracle database.Especially about the terms

1. Start With
2. Connect By
3. No cycle
4. Prior.
5. NULLIF

Also why it is used when comparing with normal queries.Also i have given a sample query,explain me with the help of this Query as it will be useful to all.

```
SELECT SID
FROM student
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PARENT_sid = PRIOR SID
  START WITH sid                = prior NULLIF(parent_sid,sid)
```

Comment: How about reading the Oracle online documentation? By the way, SQL Developer is a client tool, and not the database itself. **SQL language is not the same as SQL Developer**.

Comment: [Hierarchical Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) documentation.

Comment: SQL Developer is a client tool, and not the database itself. SQL language is not the same as SQL Developer---**Already knows that @LalitKumarB

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [**Hierarchical Queries**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332):

- **START WITH** specifies the root row(s) of the hierarchy.
- **CONNECT BY** specifies the relationship between parent rows and child rows of the hierarchy.
- The **NOCYCLE** parameter instructs Oracle Database to return rows from a query even if a CONNECT BY loop exists in the data.
- **PRIOR** operator - In a hierarchical query, one expression in condition must be qualified with the PRIOR operator to refer to the parent row.

From the Oracle documentation on [**NULLIF**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions128.htm#SQLRF00681):

> NULLIF compares expr1 and expr2. If they are equal, then the function
>   returns null. If they are not equal, then the function returns expr1.
>   You cannot specify the literal NULL for expr1.
>
> If both arguments are numeric datatypes, then Oracle Database
>   determines the argument with the higher numeric precedence, implicitly
>   converts the other argument to that datatype, and returns that
>   datatype. If the arguments are not numeric, then they must be of the
>   same datatype, or Oracle returns an error.

The NULLIF function is logically equivalent to the following CASE expression:

```
CASE WHEN expr1 = expr 2 THEN NULL ELSE expr1 END
```